# Can I get 'way' information via OverpassAPI in offline

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, osm.pbf

I know the following code works well to get the 'way' information via OverpassAPI(or overpy) library.

```
from OSMPythonTools.overpass import Overpass  
overpass = Overpass()
query = "way[highway](around:3,35.356309, 139.598544);(._;>;);out;"
result = overpass.query(query)
```

But I want to know whether I can get such information in offline environment or not.
I can prepare the planet.osm data from https://planet.openstreetmap.org/ in local.
How can I get 'way' information with planet.osm data in offline?
Thank you.

Comment: You can install a local Overpass API instance if you want to perform these queries offline.

Comment: I understand I can use Overpass API offline by building instance server like https://hub.docker.com/r/wiktorn/overpass-api.
My issue is clear now, Thanks!